# Find median for an image array for background estimation fast in Swift/ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, opencv, vdsp, vimage, accelerate

I need to estimate the background across multiple frames of a stationary video (not-moving camera). I have a number of frames and want to calculate the median for each pixel across all frames (usually 10 to 100 frames). I was able to do that with brute force but the performance is just awful (it takes 30-120 seconds to calculate). In `Python` with `NumPy` I can achieve this in a single `np.median` call:

```py
medianFrames = [im1, im2, im3, im4]
medianFrame = np.median(medianFrames, axis=0).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
```

In Objective-C the algorithm is below, very slow because it enumerates each pixel, creates an array for each component (R,G,B), and then calculates median value. It works but it's super slow (uses `OpenCV` `Mat` for image manipulation):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < result.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.cols; j++) {
            NSMutableArray *elements_B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arr.count];
            NSMutableArray *elements_G = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arr.count];
            NSMutableArray *elements_R = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arr.count];
            for(int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < arr.count; frameIndex++) {
                Mat frame = matArray[frameIndex];
                int B = frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
                int G = frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
                int R = frame.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
                elements_B[frameIndex] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:B];
                elements_G[frameIndex] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:G];
                elements_R[frameIndex] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:R];
            }
            
            NSArray *sortedB = [elements_B sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
            NSUInteger middleB = [sortedB count] / 2;
            NSNumber *medianB = [sortedB objectAtIndex:middleB];
            
            result.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = medianB.intValue;
            
            NSArray *sortedG = [elements_G sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
            NSUInteger middleG = [sortedG count] / 2;
            NSNumber *medianG = [sortedG objectAtIndex:middleG];
            
            result.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = medianG.intValue;
            
            NSArray *sortedR = [elements_R sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
            NSUInteger middleR = [sortedR count] / 2;
            NSNumber *medianR = [sortedR objectAtIndex:middleR];
            
            result.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = medianR.intValue;
        }
    }
```

The real bottleneck is an enumeration of each pixel across each image and calculating the median value. What is the best way to process multiple images and execute pixel-based math operations efficiently, as `NumPy` does?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the mean or the median?

Comment: I want to calculate median, let me edit my question to avoid confusion

Comment: I'm not familiar with opencv so I'm not posting this as an answer (because there could be a better method built in) but I imagine you could start by eliminating ObjC in the loops (use of `NSArray`, `NSNumber` etc) and drop down to C or C++. Also, instead of operating on each matrix element individually you could get the whole row as a C pointer (using `ptr<Vec3b>(i)` and process it that way.

Comment: As a related solution, if you ever need to calculate the Euclidean norm of corresponding pixels in multiple images you could convert the image stack to a single 3D matrix and call `computeNorm` with `axes =  [2] `. Note that you'd also need to convert 8-bit pixel data to 32-bit. vImage can do that for you.

BNNS function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/bnns/3783726-computenorm